# why is this function wrapped in memo?

Tags: react-native

I saw a code and a person has written this lines of code:

```
  const createdAt = useMemo(() => {
    return message && dayjs(message.createdAt).format('HH:mm');
  }, [message]);
```

Why He put dayjs in a memo, is dayjs expensive to call ?

Comment: It's best to have non-primitive memoized otherwise passing them as props triggers a re-render (because you create a new array/object/whatever at each render, and JS cannot compare them) But in this case, as the output is formatted to string, it is indeed a primitive, so no need to memoize it here IMO

Comment: @dbuchet but then I can use react.memo instead of useMemo or not ?

Comment: `memo` is for components and compare the props passed to component. `useMemo` is a hook which do not redeclare a variable across render, and depends on a dependency array. So same things (memoization) but for differents things (components / variables)